# Mule ESB: Issue w/ XML generated from MapsToXML input to DataMapper

Tags: mule, esb

I have a JDBC outbound endpoint that after performing Map To XML transformation, gives out XML in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
<record>
<field name="DESTINATION" type="java.lang.String">SFO</field>
<field name="PRICE" type="java.lang.String">500</field>
<field name="ID" type="java.lang.Integer">2</field>
</record>
</table>
```

The problem is that when I try to generate the schema for this XML for use in the datamapper , the fields that are generated from this are not usable (it only shows field , In the mapping file I get this message when I try to hover over it :
'The attribute cannot be dragged since it does not belong to 'Current Element Mapping'
How do I use my XML so that I can map those fields to either another CSV, database or some other entity?

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying to map (via DataMapper) Map object directly to CSV or anything you'd like ? 
 If you need this intermediary XML format, you can also use DataMapper for the initial Map->XML mapping and configure the way you want it to look like (instead using MapsToXML).